# Trig equation when one side is negative

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm solving
$$-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - 2x\right)=\cos\left(5x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)$$

In standard procedure, I would normally set the contents of cosines equal to each other. I'm however confused by the presence of a negative sign at the beginning of LHS. Is the following reasoning correct?

I imagine the angles $(\frac{\pi}{2}-2x)$ and $(5x-\frac{\pi}{6})$ as being equal in size.
I'm thinking of $(5x-\frac{\pi}{6})$ as an angle whose cosine gives some value g on the unit circle's x-axis. Since there is a negative on LHS, I'd like $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2} - 2x)$ to be equal to -g, since $-(-g)$ would produce g. But in order to achieve -g for $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2} - 2x)$, I would have to subtract $(\frac{\pi}{2}-2x)$ from $\pi$ inside the LHS's cos argument, thus obtaining
$$-\cos(\pi - (\frac{\pi}{2} - 2x))=\cos(5x-\frac{\pi}{6}) \implies \pi - \frac{\pi}{2} + 2x = 5x-\frac{\pi}{6}$$ and then solving the equation as usual. Correct approach?

Comment: $cos(\alpha) = -cos(\beta) \iff  (\alpha = \beta + \pi + 2k\pi)$ or $( \alpha = \pi - \beta + 2k\pi)$

Comment: Which can also be written as $\iff\alpha\pm\beta=(2k+1)\pi.$

Comment: In this case, a better approach would be to use $\cos a+\cos b=2\cos\frac{a+b}2\cos\frac{a-b}2$. The solutions are the values where one or the other of the cosines is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $$\cos \left( \tfrac{\pi}{2} + a \right) \equiv -\sin \left( a \right)$$

to simplify the LHS with $a=-2 x$ as

$$-\cos \left( \tfrac{\pi}{2} - 2 x \right) = - ( - \sin\left( -2 x\right) ) = \sin\left( -2 x \right) \tag{1}$$

and to simplify the RHS as with $a = 5 x - \tfrac{2 \pi}{3}$

$$\cos\left( \tfrac{\pi}{2} + (5 x - \tfrac{2 \pi}{3}) \right) = -\sin \left( 5 x - \tfrac{2 \pi}{3} \right) = \sin \left( \tfrac{2\pi}{3}-5 x \right) \tag{2}$$

Now equate (1) to (2) to get

$$ \sin\left( -2 x \right) = \sin \left( \tfrac{2\pi}{3}-5 x \right)$$

and proceed from there

Comment: $\sin a =\sin b$ has two solutions $a=b+2n\pi$ and $a=-b+(2n+1)\pi$. Try plugging in your $x$ for $n=1$ into the original equation

Comment: @Andrei - thank you.

Comment: Interesting, may I ask why you chose to change all the trig functions to sin rather than cos? To avoid the $-cos(a) = cos(b)$ situation?

Comment: @saner - because $$\text{-}\sin(a) = \sin(\text{-}a)$$

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Yes, but what is the motivation behind using that fact?

Comment: @saner - to make the LHS function identical to the RHS function so as to match the arguments. Alternatively you could use $\text{-}\cos(a) = \cos(a+\pi)$